# Mapping the Excel F2 to a different button does not work when F2 is re-mapped to open and application

Tags: autohotkey

I mapped {F2} to open/start "OneNote"
I want to use the XButton2 to take the function of F2 when Excel is the active application. 
However, pressing of the XButton2 always activtates OneNote.

I tried everything to make this work.

```
F2::
    IF WinExist("ahk_exe ONENOTE.EXE") {
        WinActivate
    }
RETURN

#IfWinActive ahk_class XLMAIN 
$XButton2::
    send {F2}
return
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you're triggering the F2 hotkey by sending F2.
To avoid this, you'll want to use the [`$` modifier](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols) on your F2 hotkey like so:
`$F2::`
Seems like you actually have it on your XButton2 hotkey? Maybe you were on the right track but have it on the wrong hotkey? Either way, it isn't doing anything for you, so you can remove it.
(Alternative [`#UseHook`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_UseHook.htm) can be specified somewhere above, so the keyboard hook is implemented for every hotkey after it)

And now a few miscellaneous fixes about your script. In AHK simple [remaps](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) are actually done like this:
`XButton2::F2`
Sweet clean little one-liner. (One-liner hotkeys don't need a `return` under them either)

So here would be your finished product:

```
$F2::
    IF WinExist("ahk_exe ONENOTE.EXE") {
        WinActivate
    }
RETURN

#IfWinActive ahk_class XLMAIN 
XButton2::F2
#IfWinActive
```

Personally I'd also omit the brackets, since they're not required for single line if-statements. But that's just preference of course. And also not sure why you've capitalized `return`.

Comment: Hi 0x464e. Thanks very mutch. Exactly what I needed. I red several times over the section on the $ modifier. But I did not understand it. 
Solution works.